# How to render a component only on the start page in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want the "Home" component to only show on the start page. Now it's visible on every page. What should I do? I have tried some options but there is still something I'm missing.

This is my Index.js:

```
import "./index.css";
import News from "./news";
import Nav from "./nav";
import Home from "./home";
import {BrowserRouter,Route} from "react-router-dom"

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Nav />
  <Route path="/" component={Home}></Route>
    <Route path="/Nintendo"><News newsName="nintendo+games" /></Route>
    <Route path="/Playstation"><News newsName="playstation+games"/></Route>
    <Route path="/Xbox"><News newsName="xbox+games" /></Route>
    <Route path="/PC"><News newsName="pc+games" /></Route>
    <Route path="/Retro"><News newsName="retro+games" /></Route>
    <Route path="/Indie"><News newsName="indie+games" /></Route>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: you can use the switch to achieve it. here is doc link https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I believe you can add the `exact` prop to the route:

```js
<Route path="/" exact component={Home}></Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

All routes are ***inclusively*** matched and rendered within a router. The home page route path is `"/"` and will ***always*** be matched and rendered. While you *can* use the `exact` prop I don't recommend littering routes with the `exact` prop. Use the `Switch` component to ***exclusively*** match and render routes. Order the routes in inverse order of path specificity so that *more* specific paths are rendered before falling back to *less* specific paths. `"/Nintendo"` is more specific than `"/"` is more specific than `"*"`.

Example:

```
import "./index.css";
import News from "./news";
import Nav from "./nav";
import Home from "./home";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom"

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Nav />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/Nintendo">
        <News newsName="nintendo+games" />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/Playstation">
        <News newsName="playstation+games"/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/Xbox">
        <News newsName="xbox+games" />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/PC">
        <News newsName="pc+games" />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/Retro">
        <News newsName="retro+games" />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/Indie">
        <News newsName="indie+games" /> // <-- ^^^ more specific paths
      </Route>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} /> // <-- less specific path
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```